# Error: main class not found

Tags: java, compilation, main-method

When compiling the program I get the error as

**Could not find the main class: Solution. Program will exit.**

The program is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution{
   public static long[] factors(long a){
     long[] b;
     b=new long[50];
     int count=0;
     for(long i=1L;i<=a/2;i++)
       if(a%i==0) b[count++]=i;
     return b;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        int N=in.nextInt();
        long K=in.nextInt();
        long[] fact=factors(K);
        l1:
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            long num=in.nextInt();
            for(int j=0;j<fact.length;j++)
                if(num%fact[j]==0 && fact[j]!=1) {fact[j]=1;continue l1;}

        }
        int result=0;
        for(int i=0;i<fact.length;i++)
            if(fact[i]!=1) ++result;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're running the program.

Comment: what do you use for compiling this code? An IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans or with any other tool?

Comment: @LewsTherin valid Java syntax, it's what's known as a "label" (note the `continue l1;` statement that appears later.

Comment: i m running this thro terminal...
javac Solution.java
java Solution

Comment: Look at the last answer.

Comment: @JanKoester  can yu tell me what difference it makes in compiling in different compilers???
i compiled thro terminal which showed me the error said above
but when i compiled thro Intellij Idea it got compiled without any error..

Comment: @harvish problems with dependencies can occur. In an IDE like IntelliJ all needed libraries for your program are added automatically to your projects class path. If you compile it direct in a console it can happen that some libraries could not be found because you have not added them to the class path of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not compile because the `main` method is not belong to a class. Put the `main` method inside the class to solve the problem. And your code is throwing arithmetic exception `divide by zero` should be fixed like that.

```
for(int j=0;j<fact.length;j++)
  if (fact[j] != 0)
    if(num%fact[j]==0 && fact[j]!=1) {
      fact[j]=1;continue l1;
    }
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but it is in a class. There is an end brace.. the poor indentation is misleading.

Comment: the main method is within the class Solution. Still not working !!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct - it compiles and runs fine on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/Aijmd)).

The problem that you are seeing has to do with the way you are compiling and running your application. At the command line prompt, do this:

```
javac Solution.java
```

This will produce `Solution.class` file. Run it as follows:

```
java Solution
```

At this point the running program will be reading the input and producing the output on the console. It will throw exceptions if the expected input is not available because you call `nextInt` without checking for `hasInt`, but it will produce a result if you give it the input that it expects.

Comment: @It will never produce result until errors in the code is fixed.

Comment: @RomanC The same code is getting compiled in intellij idea but not compiling thro terminal.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can yu explain me what to do to correct the error?...put `hasInt` ??

Comment: @harvish Actually I've already forgot when I did it manually via console. If I need the automation of the building process I prefer the Ant or Maven. And the above is a good support for plug-ins of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> When compiling the program i get the error as
>
> **Could not find the main class: Solution. Program will exit.**

*Compiling* doesn't require any main class: you can compile helper classes independently. So the problem is apparently that you're trying to *run* a class that you haven't compiled yet. For example, if you're using the command-line tools, then you're most likely running `java` when you mean to be running `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

There are ***NO*** independent functions in the Java programming model; every procedure/function *must* be a method on some class, including the `static void main` method.